# C/C++ in Android NDK

Tags: c++, c, android-ndk

I have a C/C++ game engine made in C for Iphone, but i want to port it on Android OS. Who can help me to do that ? In my project i have Render( where i draw all the scene) and a function Accelerometer where i use the accelerometer. I want to use java JNI to make a bridge between java and C/C++. I want to write my code in C/C++ because i can port it on different devices.

Comment: Some company or individual who does programming work for hire can help you. Look for one with Android experience.

Stack Overflow is not a proper venue to find one. Rent-a-coder would probably work better for you.

Comment: If you want to do it yourself, then reading the documentation on NDK and Android will help you. Here's a nice "Getting started" guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html

Comment: My project will be open source and for learning. I don't want to make money from it. I want to make a community and an open source project.